# Problems with an exercise?

Tags: c++

I'm doing the following exercise of the Stroustrup's book:

> Create a program to find all the prime numbers between 1 and 100.
>   There is a classic method for doing this, called the “Sieve of Eratosthenes.”
>   If you don’t know that method, get on the web and look it up. Write your program using this method.

I've understood the exercise but I'm having problems with how to implement it in C++.
This is the code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> nonprimi;
    vector<int> primi;

    for(int i=0; i <=100; i++){
        primi.push_back(i);
    }

    int numero = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        numero += 2;
        numero == nonprimi[i];
    }

    numero = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        numero += 3;
        numero == nonprimi[i];
    }

    numero = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        numero += 5;
        numero == nonprimi[i];
   }

   numero = 7;
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       numero += 7;
       numero == nonprimi[i];
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < nonprimi.size(); i++){
       if(primi[i] != nonprimi[i])
       cout << "\n" << primi[i] << "\n";
   }

return 0;
}
```

Could you provide me with some advice that will help me implement the algorithm successfully?

Note:  Probably I should read the chapter again .

Comment: You have to tell us what the problem is in order for us to figure out where it is; is it a compiler error message, do you get the wrong result, what's wrong?

Comment: The program starts but the output is absent.

Comment: `numero == nonprimi[i]` this does nothing.

Comment: All of your accesses to `nonprimi` are undefined as `nonprimi` hasn't had any space allocated. Also, your use of `==` indicates that you don't know how that operator works.

Comment: When you have repetitive code that differs only with a number, this is a hint you should use an array and loop. You can put 2, 3, 5, 7 in a static const array, and loop through that, performing the logic.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Righto; meant that no space has ever been allocated. Changed my comment to reflect as such.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not understanding very well, in part for my bad english and in part because i'm at the start of c++. Can you tell me the right code to understand better how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the `primi` vector, which you push back 101 times in the first loop and it acquires a size of 101, the `nonprimi` vector never gets pushed back so it stays at a size of zero. Then, in the next loops, when you try to index its elements, a "vector subscript out of range" exception is thrown.

Also, expressions like this `numero == nonprimi[i];` are comparison statements and do not accomplish anything unless they are inside the parentheses of an `if` statement or `while` loop.

Consider this alternative:

The long `if` statement in the second `for` loop literally means, if the number from the first array (which has been populated with all integers from 0 to 99) is 2, 3, 5 or 7 or is not divisible by any of 2, 3, 5 or 7, then add it into the `primi` vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> nonprimi;
    vector<int> primi;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        nonprimi.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nonprimi.size(); i++) {
        if (((nonprimi[i] == 2) || (nonprimi[i] == 3) ||
             (nonprimi[i] == 5) || (nonprimi[i] == 7)) || 
             (nonprimi[i] % 2 != 0) && (nonprimi[i] % 3 != 0) && 
             (nonprimi[i] % 5 != 0) && (nonprimi[i] % 7 != 0)) {

            primi.push_back(i);
        }
    }           

    for (int i = 0; i < primi.size(); i++) {
        cout << primi[i] << " ";
    }

    // or in a more STL way
    // copy(primi.begin(), primi.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right, primi will have a size of 101. Edited.

Comment: It will be better if you exchange `system("pause")` with `getchar()` or simply insert a break point on a dummy statement before exiting the program

Comment: I use code blocks now and it isn't required, the program ask to press a key even if i miss getchar() or system("PAUSE")

Comment: @simplicis veritatis That's why it's commented out, to indicate it's optional

Comment: I get that is optional , however, how good option it is? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, not sure if it is ideal:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Find the prime numbers from 2, 3, 4, 5, through 100
    // using Sieve of Eratosthenes
    
    vector <int> numbers;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
        numbers.push_back(i);

    int p = 0;  // index of "numbers"

    cout << "Prime numbers:\n";
    while (p < (numbers.size() - 1)) {
        int prime = numbers[p];

        for (int i = p + prime; i < numbers.size(); i += prime)
        {
            numbers[i] = -1;    // make all non-prime numbers less than zero
        }

        
        do {
            if (p < (numbers.size() - 1)) {
                p++;    // increase the index until you encounter a positive number
            }
            else
                break;
        } while (numbers[p] < 0);
        cout << prime << endl;
    }
    

}
```